# Memory error with python 64bit

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, out-of-memory

I have added the code and the error message.
I have installed python3 64bit and anaconda 3.5 and I am facing memory error when I am extracting features from text file that result in a 2D array of 264,549 X21,000 . I am using Windows 10 64bit and 16GB Ram.
when I check the python version I have this is the result:
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 19 2017, 08:03:39) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

is it a problem with python? or the array cannot be fitted into the memory?

This is the error I have:

> extracting the list of bow from training data...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tweet_fea_bow.py", line 27, in 
>       train_bow=vect.fit_transform(training).toarray()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 964, in toarray
>       return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 252, in toarray
>       B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 1039, in _process_toarray_args
>       return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
>   MemoryError

```
import sys,os,traceback
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

print(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
  print( "Reading data from file " + (sys.argv[1]))
  query_file_name = sys.argv[1] 
  tf_num = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
  print ('Number of arguments = %d, expecting 1 arguments, program     terminated.') % (len(sys.argv) - 1)
sys.exit (1)

training=open('../training_data.txt','r').read().splitlines()
print('extracting bow from training data...')
vect=CountVectorizer(min_df=tf_num, ngram_range=(2,2))
train_bow=vect.fit_transform(training).toarray()
print('training matrix size:',train_bow.shape)
print('writing the training matrix...')
outfile=(path+'../bow_bi_gram_%s.npy'%(tf_num))
try:
   np.save(outfile,train_bow)
except:
   print('error')
   e=sys.exc_info()
   print(e)
print('extracting bow from testing data..')
testing=open('../testing_red_len_remove_@andurl.txt','r')
.read().splitlines()
test_bow=vect.transform(testing).toarray()
print('size of testing matrix:',test_bow.shape)
print('writing the testing matrix...')
outfile=('../testing_bow_bi_gram_%s.npy'%(tf_num))
np.save(outfile,test_bow)
```

Comment: How can I reproduce this error?

Comment: You're going to have to give us the exact error code, and more specifics about what you are doing for us to help you.

Comment: plz show us your original error message?

Comment: @ElisByberi I updated my question to include the code and the error msg. Thank you

Comment: @PaydenK.Pringle I provided the exact error msg and the code. Thank you

Comment: @DRPK I have added the error I got when running the script.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just make the operation yourself : 264,549 * 21,000  * size of  a cell = ?

Generally such data must be treated chunk by chunk.